# Where to store Interfaces in a Decoupled Architecture in my C# Solution?

Tags: dll, architecture, interface, decouple

I know this question might seem to be answered before, but I feel that the answer varies from case to case, so after reading several posts, I'm not sure in my case which is the best for my architecture.

I have a Component Library that has a Data Model and basic functionality that should be available to any application implementing this component.

I have a boundary for this component which has an interface IReader to load and process files from the disk and IDataMapper to provide Database access and CRUD operations.
a few other interfaces for specific functionality like IObjectComparison to compare objects, IXMLSerialization fro XML serialization.

I'm not sure where to store the definition of these interfaces.

The options are:

1)- Within the core Library, then when I write the implementations I will have to include the implementation libraries within this core component with I'd like to maintain decopled from the implementations.

2)- In a separate library project (Assembly). All interfaces there and included to the core component and included by the implementation libraries.

3) - In the implementation Libraries, then the core component will have to include the implementation libraries.

The only case where it seems reasonable decoupled is if I put all interfaces in a separate assembly library where Core component includes and any implementations I might need.

What do you guys think are Pros/Cons of the best option?
All I want to achieve is a decoupled architecture.

So when I do

Constructor:

```
CoreComponent(IReader Reader, IDataMapper Mapper)

new CoreComponent(WindowsReader, SQLServerMapper)
```

and don't have to include **WindowsReader** or **SQLServerMapper** into the Core Component

Cheers.

Comment: Physically? Printed out in a vault maybe? ;p

Answer (score 3):

I would go for option 1 - Core Library as it is accordance with how we do in [DDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design). In DDD we used to put IRepository interfaces in Domain Layer instead of DAL or any other such layer.

[DIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) says the higher level component would own the interface, as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) says...

> where interfaces defining the behavior/services required by the high-level component are owned by, and exist within the high-level component's package.

This is most common practice but not a strict rule.

Option 2 is fine but you need to refer two DLLs in other projects but with option 1 only one reference is needed. Option 3 is not appropriate.

Hope it would help. Thanks.